# Linq RemoveAll for a predicate condition on a list inside the collection

Tags: c#, linq

I for the life of me cannot figure out what this LINQ query needs to be. I do fine on standard LINQ queries but in this case I need to check the condition of items in a list within a collection.

**The Task:**

I need to remove all messages in the collection where their list of recipients does not have all there handles containing a certain string i.e. "thiscompany.com".

**My Attempt So Far:**

```
// Remove internal messages
var internalMessages = messages._results
    .Where(x => x.recipients.All(y => y.handle.Contains("somecompany.com")));
messages._results = messages._results.Except(internalMessages).ToList();
```

As far as I understand this approach would work fine I would just need to implement equality checking on the Message object but for certain reasons I am unable to do this. I know there must be a way with LINQ to execute a one liner that removes all messages based on this sub condition of the Recipients List but I just can't figure out where to go from here.

**Message Object:**

```
public class Message
{
    public _Links _links { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool is_inbound { get; set; }
    public float created_at { get; set; }
    public string blurb { get; set; }
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public List<Recipient> recipients { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; }
    public MessageMetadata metadata { get; set; }
}
```

**Recipient Object:**

```
public class Recipient
{
    public _Links _links { get; set; }
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler:

```
message._result = messages._results
.Where(x => x.recipients.Any(y => !y.handle.Contains("somecompany.com"))).ToList();
```

Or

```
messages._results
.RemoveAll(x => !x.recipients.All(y => y.handle.Contains("somecompany.com")));
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly doesn't the first code snippet say set all results to results where all recipient handles do not match somecompany.com? I'm ok to have at least one instance of somecompany.com as long as they aren't all somecompany.com. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I think actually now that I am looking at it, your second code snippet is basically what I need except swap out Any for All. Since if I understand it correctly that would remove all messages where all recipients listed contain somecompany.com.

Comment: I have already updated the answer. The first one keep all records that has at least one handle without "somecompany.com". The second one remove all records that has all handle is "somecomany.com". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cName` is the string you want to exclude. Assuming you will separately take care of the fact that `cName` could be null or empty or whitespaces, just do:

```
var allMessages = messages._results;
var externalMessages = allMessages
   .Where(message => !message.recipients.All(to => to.handle.Contains(cName)))
   .ToList();
```